# Can't show full data after join table in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

Here is my `PROCEDURE` on the model:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `service_tasks_read`(
IN i_user_id    INT(255))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tasks LEFT JOIN projects ON tasks.project_id = projects.id WHERE projects.manage_user_id = i_user_id; 
END
```

Here is the running sample result:
[image]

Here is the storedprocedure's model:

```
public function service_tasks_read($aUserId)
{
    $r_result = $this->db->query("CALL service_tasks_read('".$aUserId."')");

    return $r_result;
}
```

So, when I print it back in my controller like this:

```
    $aData = $CI->storedprocedure->service_tasks_read($aUserId);

    for($i = 0; $i < $aData->num_rows(); $i++)
    {
        echo('$i    '.$i.': ');
        print_r($aData->_fetch_assoc($i));
        echo('<br/>');
    }
```

Here is the result:

```
$i 0: Array (
    [id] => 3
    [project_id] => 3
    [name] => #SYS#_DEFAULT
    [status] => 0
    [due_datetime] => 2013
    [manage_user_id] => 47
) 
$i 1: Array (
    [id] => 3
    [project_id] => 3
    [name] => #SYS#_DEFAULT
    [status] => 0
    [due_datetime] => 2013
    [manage_user_id] => 47
) 
$i 2: Array (
    [id] => 3
    [project_id] => 3
    [name] => #SYS#_DEFAULT
    [status] => 0
    [due_datetime] => 2013
    [manage_user_id] => 47
) 
$i 3: Array (
    [id] => 3
    [project_id] => 3
    [name] => #SYS#_DEFAULT
    [status] => 0
    [due_datetime] => 2013
    [manage_user_id] => 47
)
```

It can't show me back the `id,project_id,name, status,due_datetime` in the tasks table. What did I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: in Codeigniter why can you return$aData->result()or $sData->result_array().

Comment: `$CI->storedprocedure->service_tasks_read` I haven't seen this syntax before.. is it a library? does it have `next()` method?

Comment: Dear all, I added the model's code, the `storedprocedure` is a model name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply return the result in object format

```
public function service_tasks_read($aUserId)
{
    $r_result = $this->db->query("CALL service_tasks_read('".$aUserId."')");

    return $r_result->result(); // for array $r_result->result_array();
}
```